# Can SQL formated (currency) query be called by Json?

Tags: php, sql, json, ajax

I'm making a datatable, calling my data(JSON) by ajax, so i can't format my columns manually so instead, formatted directly to currency in SQL 2012

The problem is, when i try to use the Json with the concat in my datatable, the format disapeares. Is there a way to do this?

i tried:

```
FORMAT(bd.dbo.table.column, 'C', 'en-us') AS 'R1',
```

AND

```
concat('$',SUM(bd.dbo.table.column)) as R2
```

both work just fine in SQL but when i try them in Postman only the concat gives me the currency symbol.

edit**

[this is how i make the call](https://jsfiddle.net/218jqhg3/)

my json gives me this

{"data":[{"col1":"0106","col2":"5","col3":4,"col4":3,"PENDIENTE":22029.328,"PENDIENTE2":"$22,029.33","PENDIENTE3":"$22029.3"}]}

this is my query

```
SELECT 
    database.dbo.table1.col1,
    database.dbo.table1.col2,
    database.dbo.table2.col3,
    database.dbo.table1.col4,

    sum(database.dbo.table2.colMoney*
        database.dbo.table2.colMoney2) as PENDIENTE,

    FORMAT(sum(database.dbo.table2.colMoney*
        database.dbo.table2.colMoney2), 'C', 'en-us') AS PENDIENTE2,

    concat('$',sum(database.dbo.table2.colMoney*
        database.dbo.table2.colMoney2)) as PENDIENTE3
FROM
    database.dbo.table1,
    database.dbo.table2,
    database.dbo.table3
WHERE
    database.dbo.table1.ID = 
    database.dbo.table2.ID
AND
    database.dbo.table2.colMoney > 0 
GROUP BY    
    database.dbo.table1.col1,
    database.dbo.table1.col2,
    database.dbo.table2.col3,
    database.dbo.table1.col4
```

the thing is in the table neither currency simbol nor format will be shown

Comment: JSON is a text representation of data structure(s). IT cannot call anything

Comment: Can you a simplified version of the SQL query you are using and also the ajax call and how you handle the data once you get it? Also I am not sure why you say you cant format your columns manually? Could you clarify?

Comment: hi @Dzyann i edited my question... hope this makes it clearer, thanks for your help!